# Does the Verizon HTC One (M8) restrict GPS in China?

Tags: gps, localization, gps-tracking, htc-one-m8

This is a cross-post of ["Why does my phone's GPS not work in China?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45231/why-does-my-phones-gps-not-work-in-china/45233)

Based on some of the answers and comments there, I am attempting to figure out what GPS sensor is being used in my phone, and what, if any restrictions Verizon and/or HTC and/or Google has placed on it.

I am currently in Beijing, China now, and have a China Unicom SIM card in my phone, not that it makes any difference - the GPS doesn't work with my Verizon SIM in either.

My phone:

- Model number: HTC6525LVW
- Hardware version: 0004
- Android: 5.0.1
- HTC Sense version: 6.0
- Software #: 4.17.605.5
- HTC SDK API level: 6.55
- Kernel version: 3.4.0-ga9a3f03 and@ABM010 #1 SMP PREEMPT
- Baseband version: 1.12.20.1211
- Build number: 4.17.605.5 CL452965 release-keys
- PRI Version: 2.90_002
- PRL version: 00000
- ERI Version: 5

Comment: Please note that [crossposting is not welcome at SE sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/192154), even if they would fit on multiple of them. Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. Apart from that, this is an Android-independent device question, and thus even off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it doesn't. I was simply running into a classic "urban canyon" problem.